# Disable window from calling SetForegroundWindow

Tags: c++, winapi, lost-focus, setforegroundwindow

I have a serious problem on my work machine with a `third` party software window stealing keyboard focus, using a `winapi` monitor tool i detect that whenever the windows steal focus it first call [SetForegroundWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow).

While searching about, i have found the `winapi` [LockSetForegroundWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-locksetforegroundwindow), wow i thought i had solved the problem, however, `LockSetForegroundWindow` blocks me from activating any other window.

I also found that would be possible to 'block' the window from calling `SetForegroundWindow` using a `hook`, but i have no knowledge about hooking, would like to ask if there's something else i could try.

Comment: Per the `SetForegroundWindow()` documentation, the only way the other program could "steal" the focus is if it already had permission to do so. You can't take away that permission if you weren't the one to grant the permission in the first place.

Comment: ^ Unless application uses UIAutomation, hotkey, SwitchToThisWindow, SW_MINIMIZE/SW_RESTORE or other trick to force itself into foreground.

Comment: Remove the third party software

Answer (score 1):

Usually calling `SetForegroundWindow()` isn't bad. Since Windows XP, there is a lock that no program do this without being allowed to do this. Read the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow

This are the exceptions:

> - The process is the foreground process.
> - The process was started by the foreground process.
> - The process received the last input event.
> - There is no foreground process.
> - The process is being debugged.
> - The foreground process is not a Modern Application or the Start Screen.
> - The foreground is not locked (see LockSetForegroundWindow).
> - The foreground lock time-out has expired (see SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT in SystemParametersInfo).
> - No menus are active.

But when the third party tools uses `AttachThreadInput()`, it bypasses all these checks.

Just delete this "bad" software. Contact the developers.

Comment: The list of exceptions is wrong, and has been so for more than a decade. Calling `AttachThreadInput` no longer allows a non-foreground process to steal foreground activation permission from the foreground thread, as of some version of Windows 10 (19-something, I guess?).

Comment: Besides, this has never been a security issue. Security is handled through UIPI (and access control).

Comment: The list was taken from the current docs. And yes it is not a security issue, I changed the text.

Comment: As far as I see (also in my code). AttachThreadInput to the current window that is the for ground window and than using SetForegroundWindow still works.

Comment: Yes, the *"current docs"* are wrong, and have been so for ages.